# Trying to understand memory error with add_edge in networkx in python with largeish integer graph

Tags: python, memory, networkx

has anybody else had this error in add_edge with networkx in python?
Any advice on how to resolve it would be warmly appreciated.

This is a python program exploring some number properties through network analysis with networkx.

The error is:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\networkx\classes\graph.py", line 718, in add_edge
self.adj[v][u] = datadict
MemoryError
```

The code is just joining each num to some integer properties of that number for late analysis:

```
maxnum = 10000001
for num in range(2,maxnum):
    G.add_node(num)
    #get properties (ints) and make unique
    properties = list(set(generate_properties(num)))  
    for p in properties:
        G.add_edge(num,p)
```

The thing that gets me is when maxnum is 10^6 it works and when 10^7 I get this error.
More than anything I would like to understand why the memory error is happening.
Thanks!

Aside: my machine has 4GB of RAM if that's relevant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number is *huge*.

`4 Gb / 10000001 = 430 bytes per node` or 100 C integers. Since Python interpreter is obviously not the only program running on your machine, and probably each node/edge takes some amount of memory (edge is *at least* 2 integers) you won't be able to have more than 50 edges per node. And that's just the lower bound, Python is of course much less memory efficient.

Also, if you run on a 32-bit platform you probably have less then 4 Gb available (no more than 3 Gb on Windows). So running out of memory is not a surpise at all.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated. I read in another answer that Python should be doing memory swapping. Is there any reason why the program can't manage memory to make this possible, or is this a naive question? Thanks

Comment: @aldorath That's not about Python, that's about your OS. You are running on Windows and I'm not sure I can explain you why you get this error. On Linux that would mean that you are out of RAM and out of swap space. Probably Windows doesn't bother swapping in this case. Or maybe you actually ran out of swap. This is really very OS specific.